# Videojs seekbar not visible on Live stream

Tags: reactjs, video-streaming, video.js

I'm using videojs 7.21 to display past live stream (using NX Witness HTTP Streaming (not HLS streaming). So, my url source is live stream and at the bottom left conor of the video, there is a text called 'Live' and only button (play) is visible with my below code.
My stream is longer than 30s and using `liveui: true` also not working: according to this [github issue](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/7095).

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import videojs from "video.js";
import "video.js/dist/video-js.css";

const MyVideo = ({ id, videoUrl, options }) => {
  const videoNode = useRef(null);
  const playerRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (videoNode.current) {
      const player = videojs(videoNode.current, options, () => {
        console.log("Video.js player is ready");
      });

      playerRef.current = player;
      player.src(videoUrl);

      player.on("error", (event) => {
        console.log("Video.js error:", event);
      });

      return () => {
        if (playerRef.current) {
          playerRef.current.dispose();
        }
      };
    }
  }, [videoUrl, options, isOpen]);

  return (
    <div data-vjs-player>
      <video
        controls
        id={`${id}`}
        ref={videoNode}
        className="video-js vjs-big-play-centered custom-video-js-class vjs-control-bar"
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyVideo;
```

```
<MyVideo
    id={data.cameraId}
    options={{
        autoplay: true,
        controls: true,
        controlBar: {
            playToggle: true,
            volumePanel: false,
            pictureInPictureToggle: false,
            progressControl: {
              seekBar: true,
            },
            currentTimeDisplay: true,
            timeDivider: true,
            durationDisplay: true,
            remainingTimeDisplay: true,
            playbackRateMenuButton: false,
          },
          muted: true,
          preload: "auto",
          aspectRatio: "16:9",
          fluid: true,
          responsive: true,
          liveui: true,
          // liveTracker: {
          //   trackingThreshold: 10, // this is not also working
          // },
        }}
        videoUrl={my-live-stream-link.webm}
        // videoUrl="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.webm" // this link is working. i can see controls (especially seekbar)
        />
```

The problem is related with my link, and not related with CSS either, as using this link `http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.webm`, I can see the desired controls.

> Seekbar is visible on Firefox, but not on Chrome.

Comment: Is this helpful?  https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/6630

Comment: @Siri I would first test if seeking is even possible in livestreams played with VideoJS. You can do a quick one with a `<button>` and see if clicking can seek the video back minus 5 seconds. If yes, then investigate having the seek bar to be visible... Else if no, then stop since a seek bar will be useless.

Comment: not working. i'm on Chrome. @David

Comment: Including the actual stream URL would be most useful here.

Comment: @Siri **(1)** I tested a livestream via loading an M3U8 file and it shows the seekbar in Chrome (no "live" text). VideoJS was loaded using : `https://unpkg.com/video.js@7.21.0/dist/video.js` to match your _"I'm using videojs 7.21"_ ... **(2)** _"So, my url source is live stream"_ what does that even to a programmer or to the software? You need a file or some bytes (of a video format) to send to the player. **(3)** If you can't put an example link of the page with issue then you might not get a fast answer here.